# Partial differentiation becomes regular differentiation?

Tags: statistics, partial-differential-equations, notation

I am reading a book on the Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing by Steven M. Kay. Chapter 3 discusses the Cramér-Rao Lower Bound (CRLB) which places a lower bound of the variance of any unbiased estimator. In chapter 3.11, they apply the theory of the CRLB to several practical signal processing examples. My question is related to one of those examples.

## Background information

Suppose a signal $s(t)$ being transmitted from a source, positioned a distance $d$ away from a sensor $x(t)$. The time it takes for the signal to propagate and arrive at the sensor would be $\tau = \frac{d}{c}$, where $c$ is the propagation speed of the signal medium. The signal arriving at the sensor can be described as

$$
\begin{equation}
  x(t) = s(t - \tau) + w(t) \hspace{2em}\textrm{for } 0 \le t \le T,
\end{equation}
$$

where the transmitted signal is assumed to be active over the interval $[0, T_s]$. The transmitted signal is bandlimited at $B$ Hz, and we observe the signal at the receiver for a time duration of $T = T_s + \tau$. The noise $w(t)$ is modeled as White Gaussian Noise (WGN) with a variance equal to $\sigma^2 = N_0 B$. Since the signal is bandlimited and is sampled at the Nyquist rate, the interval between two consecutive samples is $\Delta = 1 / (2B)$. We can write the previous equation as a discrete data model:

$$
\begin{equation}
    x[n] = s(n\Delta - \tau) + w[n] \hspace{2em} \textrm{for } n = 0,1,\dots,N-1,
\end{equation}
$$

where $N = T / \Delta$. Since in the observed signal, the transmitted signal is only present over the interval $\tau \le t \le \tau + T_s$, $x[n]$ becomes
where $M = T_s / \Delta$, and $n_0 = \tau / \Delta$. With this formulation, we can evaluate the Cramér-Rao Lower Bound (CRLB) for any unbiased estimator $\hat\tau$.

## Actual question

\begin{equation}
    \textrm{var}(\hat\tau) \ge \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} \left( \frac{\partial s[n; \tau]}{\partial\tau} \right)^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \color{red}{= \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum\limits_{n=n_0}^{n_0 + M - 1} \left( \frac{\partial s(n\Delta - \tau)}{\partial \tau} \right)^2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \color{red}{= \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum\limits_{n=n_0}^{n_0 + M - 1} \left( \frac{ds(t)}{dt}\Big|_{t=n\Delta - \tau} \right)^2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{M - 1} \left( \frac{ds(t)}{dt}\Big|_{t=n\Delta} \right)^2}
\end{equation}

My question is only related to the red part of the equation above. **Why can we swap out the partial differentiation of $s(n\Delta - \tau)$ in $\tau$ for the regular differentiation of $s(t)$ in $t$, evaluated at $t=n\Delta-\tau$?** I must admit I'm not really familiar with this type of notation and I don't know if there are any underlying assumptions happening.

Comment: You can treat this as an instance of the multivariable Chain Rule, where s(t) is  modified by replacing t with a linear function  t= c-$\tau$ in which $c= n \Delta$. But more fundamentally this can be deduced directly from the definition of a partial derivative as an ordinary derivative with all other variables held constant.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't see it. Could you further elaborate why this is the case?